# how to populate select box with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a requirement in which when i click on a element of a list , the element gets shown as a selected option in the select box

i need to use native select box only , not to mention the elements in the list are present in the select dropdown

```
<button class="quick">QuickLink</button>

<div class="list">
<ul class="apps">
    <li>CAPM</li>
    <li>GCS</li>
    <li>GRS</li>
</ul>
</div>

<select class="xyz">
<option>CAPM</option>
<option>GRS</option>
<option>BDS</option>
<option>CCAS</option>
<option>WEDAT</option>
<option>SDP</option>
</select>
```

jsfiddle link --> https://jsfiddle.net/8s31w4t9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the `click` event with `li` and use these methods:

1. [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

   > Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.
2. [`.val( value )`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

   > Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$('.apps li').click(function () {
    //Get the text of clicked element
    var text = $(this).text();

    //Set the value of select 
    $('.xyz').val(text);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2jqfpjLk/)

Comment: While this answers the question, I repeat what I said in my answer: "what if you want your `li` to have different text to the contents of the `option` element?"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you want the `click` handler to be on your `li`s, not your `ul`. And secondly, you better use the `val` function and specify the text you have in the list to be the `val` of the `select`:

```
$('.apps li').click(function(){
    $('.xyz').val($(this).text());
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s31w4t9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$(function(){

   $('.apps li').click(function(){
       $clicked = $(this);
       $('.xyz option').each(function(){
           if ($(this).text() == $clicked.text()) {
              $(this).prop('selected', true);
           }
       });
    });
 });
```

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8s31w4t9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
$(function(){
  $('.apps > li').click(function() {
    $('.xyz').val(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.apps').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $('.xyz').val(this.innerHTML);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes to make your code flexible. And what if you want your `li` to have different text to the contents of the `option` element?

```
<ul data-select-target=".xyz">
    <li data-select-val="1">CAPM</li>
    <li data-select-val="2">GRS</li>
    <li data-select-val="3">BDS</li>
</ul>

<select class="xyz">
    <option value="1">CAPM</option>
    <option value="2">GRS</option>
    <option value="3">BDS</option>
    <option value="4">CCAS</option>
    <option value="5">WEDAT</option>
    <option value="6">SDP</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('[data-select-target] li').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).data('select-val');
    var target = $(this).closest('ul').data('select-target');
    $(target).val(val);
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvL4v3Lg/)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following solution:

```
$(function(){
    $('.apps li').css("cursor","pointer")
    $('.apps li').click(function () {
    $('.xyz').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z7s36noq/

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't notice it. I have modified it a bit so that the `li` looks clickable